# Littlewood polynomial root heatmap

Tags: c++

a Littlewood polynomial is a polynomial where each coefficient is ether -1 or 1 and when the complex roots of them it produces a nice image. As a  result I decided to make a program in c++ that plots a heatmap of the complex roots of randomly chosen Littlewood polynomials. Moreover at first I thought it would be as using GSL(gnu scientific library) as it already had a polynomial solver and libpng. However I after implementing a basic version of it using GSL I realized that GSL was to slow to use. Consequently that meant I had to find another polynomial library and after a little searching I found this https://www.codeproject.com/articles/674149/a-real-polynomial-class-with-root-finder. Then after cleaning up that library and learning how to use libpng it was mostly smooth sailing. However my main concerns are that I could be still be ways of improving the performance of the code that I don't know of and that I could still improve the code quality in ways that I don't know of.

`png.hh`

```
#ifndef PNG_HH
#define PNG_HH
#include <png.h>

namespace png
{
    void write_image(char const *filename, std::uint8_t const *image_data, std::uint32_t image_width, std::uint32_t image_height)
    {
        /* create a zeroed out png_image struct */
        png_image output_png;
        std::memset(&output_png, 0, sizeof(output_png));
        output_png.version = PNG_IMAGE_VERSION;
        output_png.format = PNG_FORMAT_GRAY;
        output_png.width = image_width;
        output_png.height = image_height;

        /* write the png file */
        png_image_write_to_file(&output_png, filename, 0, image_data, image_height, nullptr);

        /* cleanup */
        png_image_free(&output_png);
    }
}
#endif
```

`PolynomialRootFinder.hh`

```
//=======================================================================
// Copyright (C) 2003-2013 William Hallahan
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
// obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
// files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction,
// including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge,
// publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software,
// and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
// subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
// included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
// EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
// OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
// NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
// HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
// WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
// FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
// OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//=======================================================================

//**********************************************************************
//  File: PolynomialRootFinder.h
//  Author: Bill Hallahan
//  Date: January 30, 2003
//
//  Abstract:
//
//    This file contains the definition for class PolynomialRootFinder.
//
//**********************************************************************

#ifndef POLYNOMIALROOTFINDER_H
#define POLYNOMIALROOTFINDER_H

#include <array>

//======================================================================
//  Class definition.
//======================================================================


template<std::int32_t degree>
struct PolynomialRootFinder
{
    std::array<double, degree + 1> m_p_vector;
    std::array<double, degree + 1> m_qp_vector;
    std::array<double, degree + 1> m_k_vector;
    std::array<double, degree + 1> m_qk_vector;
    std::array<double, degree + 1> m_svk_vector;

    std::int32_t m_n;
    std::int32_t m_n_plus_one;
    double m_real_s;
    double m_imag_s;
    double m_u;
    double m_v;
    double m_a;
    double m_b;
    double m_c;
    double m_d;
    double m_a1;
    double m_a2;
    double m_a3;
    double m_a6;
    double m_a7;
    double m_e;
    double m_f;
    double m_g;
    double m_h;
    double m_real_sz;
    double m_imag_sz;
    double m_real_lz;
    double m_imag_lz;
    double m_are;
    double m_mre;

    enum class RootStatus_T
    {
        SUCCESS,
        LEADING_COEFFICIENT_IS_ZERO,
        SCALAR_VALUE_HAS_NO_ROOTS,
        FAILED_TO_CONVERGE
    };

    PolynomialRootFinder::RootStatus_T FindRoots(double *coefficient_ptr,
        double *real_zero_vector_ptr,
        double *imaginary_zero_vector_ptr,
        std::int32_t *number_of_roots_found_ptr = 0);

    std::int32_t Fxshfr(std::int32_t l2var);

    std::int32_t QuadraticIteration(double uu, double vv);

    std::int32_t RealIteration(double &sss, std::int32_t &flag);

    std::int32_t CalcSc();

    void NextK(std::int32_t itype);

    void Newest(std::int32_t itype, double &uu, double &vv);

    void QuadraticSyntheticDivision(std::int32_t n_plus_one,
        double u,
        double v,
        double *p_ptr,
        double *q_ptr,
        double &a,
        double &b);

    void SolveQuadraticEquation(double a,
        double b,
        double c,
        double &sr,
        double &si,
        double &lr,
        double &li);
};

#include <cmath>
#include <float.h>

namespace
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  The following machine constants are used in this method.
    //
    //    f_BASE  The base of the floating postd::int32_t number system used.
    //
    //    f_ETA  The maximum relative representation error which
    //           can be described as the smallest positive floating
    //           postd::int32_t number such that 1.0 + f_ETA is greater than 1.0.
    //
    //    f_MAXIMUM_FLOAT  The largest floating postd::int32_t number.
    //
    //    f_MINIMUM_FLOAT  The smallest positive floating postd::int32_t number.
    //
    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    constexpr float f_BASE = 2.0;
    constexpr float f_ETA = FLT_EPSILON;
    constexpr float f_ETA_N = (10.0f) * f_ETA;
    constexpr float f_ETA_N_SQUARED = (100.0f) * f_ETA;
    constexpr float f_MAXIMUM_FLOAT = FLT_MAX;
    constexpr float f_MINIMUM_FLOAT = FLT_MIN;
    constexpr float f_XX_INITIAL_VALUE = (0.70710678f);
    constexpr float f_COSR_INITIAL_VALUE = (-0.069756474f);
    constexpr float f_SINR_INITIAL_VALUE = (0.99756405f);
};

//======================================================================
//  Member Function: PolynomialRootFinder::FindRoots
//
//  Abstract:
//
//    This method determines the roots of a polynomial which
//    has real coefficients. This code is based on FORTRAN
//    code published in reference [1]. The method is based on
//    an algorithm the three-stage algorithm described in
//    Jenkins and Traub [2].
//
// 1. "Collected Algorithms from ACM, Volume III", Algorithms 493-545
//    1983. (The root finding algorithms is number 493)
//
// 2. Jenkins, M. A. and Traub, J. F., "A three-stage algorithm for
//    real polynomials using quadratic iteration", SIAM Journal of
//    Numerical Analysis, 7 (1970), 545-566
//
// 3. Jenkins, M. A. and Traub, J. F., "Principles for testing
//    polynomial zerofinding programs", ACM TOMS 1,
//    1 (March 1975), 26-34
//
//
//  Input:
//
//    All vectors below must be at least a length equal to degree + 1.
//
//    coefficicent_ptr           A double precision vector that contains
//                               the polynomial coefficients in order
//                               of increasing power.
//
//    degree                     The degree of the polynomial.
//
//    real_zero_vector_ptr       A double precision vector that will
//                               contain the real parts of the roots
//                               of the polynomial when this method
//                               returns.
//
//    imaginary_zero_vector_ptr  A double precision vector that will
//                               contain the real parts of the roots
//                               of the polynomial when this method
//                               returns.
//
//    number_of_roots_found_ptr  A postd::int32_ter to an std::int32_teger that will
//                               equal the number of roots found when
//                               this method returns. If the method
//                               returns SUCCESS then this value will
//                               always equal the degree of the
//                               polynomial.
//
//  Return Value:
//
//    The function returns an enum value of type
//    'PolynomialRootFinder::RootStatus_T'.
//
//======================================================================

template<std::int32_t degree>
typename PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::RootStatus_T PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::FindRoots(
    double *coefficient_vector_ptr,
    double *real_zero_vector_ptr,
    double *imaginary_zero_vector_ptr,
    std::int32_t *number_of_roots_found_ptr)
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  The algorithm fails if the polynomial is not at least
    //  degree on or the leading coefficient is zero.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    PolynomialRootFinder::RootStatus_T status;
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Allocate temporary vectors used to find the roots.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------


    std::array<double, degree + 1> temp_vector;
    std::array<double, degree + 1> pt_vector;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  m_are and m_mre refer to the unit error in + and *
    //  respectively. they are assumed to be the same as
    //  f_ETA.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    m_are = f_ETA;
    m_mre = f_ETA;
    double lo = f_MINIMUM_FLOAT / f_ETA;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialization of constants for shift rotation.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    double xx = f_XX_INITIAL_VALUE;
    double yy = -xx;
    double cosr = f_COSR_INITIAL_VALUE;
    double sinr = f_SINR_INITIAL_VALUE;
    m_n = degree;
    m_n_plus_one = m_n + 1;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Make a copy of the coefficients in reverse order.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    std::int32_t ii = 0;

    for (ii = 0; ii < m_n_plus_one; ++ii) {
        m_p_vector[m_n - ii] = coefficient_vector_ptr[ii];
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Assume failure. The status is set to SUCCESS if all
    //  the roots are found.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    status = PolynomialRootFinder::RootStatus_T::FAILED_TO_CONVERGE;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  If there are any zeros at the origin, remove them.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    std::int32_t jvar = 0;

    while (m_p_vector[m_n] == 0.0) {
        jvar = degree - m_n;
        real_zero_vector_ptr[jvar] = 0.0;
        imaginary_zero_vector_ptr[jvar] = 0.0;
        m_n_plus_one = m_n_plus_one - 1;
        m_n = m_n - 1;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Loop and find polynomial zeros. In the original algorithm
    //  this loop was an infinite loop. Testing revealed that the
    //  number of main loop iterations to solve a polynomial of a
    //  particular degree is usually about half the degree.
    //  We loop twice that to make sure the solution is found.
    //  (This should be revisited as it might preclude solving
    //  some large polynomials.)
    //--------------------------------------------------------------


    for (std::int32_t count = 0; count < degree; ++count) {
        //----------------------------------------------------------
        //  Check for less than 2 zeros to finish the solution.
        //----------------------------------------------------------

        if (m_n <= 2) {
            if (m_n > 0) {
                //--------------------------------------------------
                //  Calculate the final zero or pair of zeros.
                //--------------------------------------------------

                if (m_n == 1) {
                    real_zero_vector_ptr[degree - 1] =
                        -m_p_vector[1] / m_p_vector[0];

                    imaginary_zero_vector_ptr[degree - 1] = 0.0;
                } else {
                    SolveQuadraticEquation(
                        m_p_vector[0],
                        m_p_vector[1],
                        m_p_vector[2],
                        real_zero_vector_ptr[degree - 2],
                        imaginary_zero_vector_ptr[degree - 2],
                        real_zero_vector_ptr[degree - 1],
                        imaginary_zero_vector_ptr[degree - 1]);
                }
            }

            m_n = 0;
            status = PolynomialRootFinder::RootStatus_T::SUCCESS;
            break;
        } else {
            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  Find largest and smallest moduli of coefficients.
            //------------------------------------------------------

            double max = 0.0;
            double min = f_MAXIMUM_FLOAT;
            double xvar;

            for (ii = 0; ii < m_n_plus_one; ++ii) {
                xvar = (double)(::fabs((double)(m_p_vector[ii])));

                if (xvar > max) {
                    max = xvar;
                }

                if ((xvar != 0.0) && (xvar < min)) {
                    min = xvar;
                }
            }

            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  Scale if there are large or very small coefficients.
            //  Computes a scale factor to multiply the coefficients
            //  of the polynomial. The scaling is done to avoid
            //  overflow and to avoid undetected underflow from
            //  std::int32_terfering with the convergence criterion.
            //  The factor is a power of the base.
            //------------------------------------------------------

            bool do_scaling_flag = false;
            double sc = lo / min;

            if (sc <= 1.0) {
                do_scaling_flag = f_MAXIMUM_FLOAT / sc < max;
            } else {
                do_scaling_flag = max < 10.0;

                if (!do_scaling_flag) {
                    if (sc == 0.0) {
                        sc = f_MINIMUM_FLOAT;
                    }
                }
            }

            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  Conditionally scale the data.
            //------------------------------------------------------

            if (do_scaling_flag) {
                std::int32_t lvar = (std::int32_t)(::log(sc) / ::log(f_BASE) + 0.5);
                double factor = ::pow((double)(f_BASE * 1.0), double(lvar));

                if (factor != 1.0) {
                    for (ii = 0; ii < m_n_plus_one; ++ii) {
                        m_p_vector[ii] = factor * m_p_vector[ii];
                    }
                }
            }

            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  Compute lower bound on moduli of zeros.
            //------------------------------------------------------

            for (ii = 0; ii < m_n_plus_one; ++ii) {
                pt_vector[ii] = (double)(::fabs((double)(m_p_vector[ii])));
            }

            pt_vector[m_n] = -pt_vector[m_n];

            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  Compute upper estimate of bound.
            //------------------------------------------------------

            xvar = (double)
                (::exp((::log(-pt_vector[m_n]) - ::log(pt_vector[0]))
                    / (double)(m_n)));

            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  If newton step at the origin is better, use it.
            //------------------------------------------------------

            double xm;

            if (pt_vector[m_n - 1] != 0.0) {
                xm = -pt_vector[m_n] / pt_vector[m_n - 1];

                if (xm < xvar) {
                    xvar = xm;
                }
            }

            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  Chop the std::int32_terval (0, xvar) until ff <= 0
            //------------------------------------------------------

            double ff;

            for (;;) {
                xm = (double)(xvar * 0.1);
                ff = pt_vector[0];

                for (ii = 1; ii < m_n_plus_one; ++ii) {
                    ff = ff * xm + pt_vector[ii];
                }
                if (ff <= 0.0) {
                    ff = 0.0;
                    break;
                }

                xvar = xm;
            }

            double dx = xvar;

            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  Do newton iteration until xvar converges to two
            //  decimal places.
            //------------------------------------------------------

            for (;;) {
                if ((double)(::fabs(dx / xvar)) <= 0.005) {
                    break;
                }

                ff = pt_vector[0];

                double df = ff;

                for (ii = 1; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                    ff = ff * xvar + pt_vector[ii];

                    df = df * xvar + ff;

                }

                ff = ff * xvar + pt_vector[m_n];

                dx = ff / df;


                xvar = xvar - dx;
            }

            double bnd = xvar;

            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  Compute the derivative as the std::int32_tial m_k_vector
            //  polynomial and do 5 steps with no shift.
            //------------------------------------------------------

            std::int32_t n_minus_one = m_n - 1;

            for (ii = 1; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                m_k_vector[ii] =
                    (double)(m_n - ii) * m_p_vector[ii] / (double)(m_n);
            }

            m_k_vector[0] = m_p_vector[0];
            double aa = m_p_vector[m_n];
            double bb = m_p_vector[m_n - 1];
            bool zerok_flag = m_k_vector[m_n - 1] == 0.0;

            std::int32_t jj = 0;

            for (jj = 1; jj <= 5; ++jj) {
                double cc = m_k_vector[m_n - 1];

                if (zerok_flag) {
                    //----------------------------------------------
                    //  Use unscaled form of recurrence.
                    //----------------------------------------------

                    for (jvar = n_minus_one; jvar > 0; --jvar) {
                        m_k_vector[jvar] = m_k_vector[jvar - 1];
                    }

                    m_k_vector[0] = 0.0;
                    zerok_flag = m_k_vector[m_n - 1] == 0.0;
                } else {
                    //----------------------------------------------
                    //  Use scaled form of recurrence if value
                    //  of m_k_vector at 0 is nonzero.
                    //----------------------------------------------

                    double tvar = -aa / cc;

                    for (jvar = n_minus_one; jvar > 0; --jvar) {
                        m_k_vector[jvar] =
                            tvar * m_k_vector[jvar - 1] + m_p_vector[jvar];
                    }

                    m_k_vector[0] = m_p_vector[0];
                    zerok_flag =
                        ::fabs(m_k_vector[m_n - 1]) <= ::fabs(bb) * f_ETA_N;
                }
            }

            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  Save m_k_vector for restarts with new shifts.
            //------------------------------------------------------

            for (ii = 0; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                temp_vector[ii] = m_k_vector[ii];
            }

            //------------------------------------------------------
            //  Loop to select the quadratic corresponding to
            //   each new shift.
            //------------------------------------------------------

            std::int32_t cnt = 0;

            for (cnt = 1; cnt <= 20; ++cnt) {
                //--------------------------------------------------
                //  Quadratic corresponds to a double shift to a
                //  non-real postd::int32_t and its complex conjugate. The
                //  postd::int32_t has modulus 'bnd' and amplitude rotated
                //  by 94 degrees from the previous shift.
                //--------------------------------------------------

                double xxx = cosr * xx - sinr * yy;
                yy = sinr * xx + cosr * yy;
                xx = xxx;
                m_real_s = bnd * xx;
                m_imag_s = bnd * yy;
                m_u = -2.0 * m_real_s;
                m_v = bnd;

                //--------------------------------------------------
                //  Second stage calculation, fixed quadratic.
                //  Variable nz will contain the number of
                //   zeros found when function Fxshfr() returns.
                //--------------------------------------------------

                std::int32_t nz = Fxshfr(20 * cnt);

                if (nz != 0) {
                    //----------------------------------------------
                    //  The second stage jumps directly to one of
                    //  the third stage iterations and returns here
                    //  if successful. Deflate the polynomial,
                    //  store the zero or zeros and return to the
                    //  main algorithm.
                    //----------------------------------------------

                    jvar = degree - m_n;
                    real_zero_vector_ptr[jvar] = m_real_sz;
                    imaginary_zero_vector_ptr[jvar] = m_imag_sz;
                    m_n_plus_one = m_n_plus_one - nz;
                    m_n = m_n_plus_one - 1;

                    for (ii = 0; ii < m_n_plus_one; ++ii) {
                        m_p_vector[ii] = m_qp_vector[ii];
                    }

                    if (nz != 1) {
                        real_zero_vector_ptr[jvar + 1] = m_real_lz;
                        imaginary_zero_vector_ptr[jvar + 1] = m_imag_lz;
                    }

                    break;

                    //----------------------------------------------
                    //  If the iteration is unsuccessful another
                    //  quadratic is chosen after restoring
                    //  m_k_vector.
                    //----------------------------------------------
                }

                for (ii = 0; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                    m_k_vector[ii] = temp_vector[ii];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  If no convergence with 20 shifts then adjust the degree
    //  for the number of roots found.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    if (number_of_roots_found_ptr != 0) {
        *number_of_roots_found_ptr = degree - m_n;
    }

    return status;
}

//======================================================================
//  Computes up to l2var fixed shift m_k_vector polynomials,
//  testing for convergence in the linear or quadratic
//  case. initiates one of the variable shift
//  iterations and returns with the number of zeros
//  found.
//
//    l2var  An std::int32_teger that is the limit of fixed shift steps.
//
//  Return Value:
//    nz   An std::int32_teger that is the number of zeros found.
//======================================================================

template<std::int32_t degree>
std::int32_t PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::Fxshfr(std::int32_t l2var)
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Evaluate polynomial by synthetic division.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    QuadraticSyntheticDivision(m_n_plus_one,
        m_u,
        m_v,
        m_p_vector.data(),
        m_qp_vector.data(),
        m_a,
        m_b);

    std::int32_t itype = CalcSc();

    std::int32_t nz = 0;
    float betav = 0.25;
    float betas = 0.25;
    float oss = (float)(m_real_s);
    float ovv = (float)(m_v);
    float ots;
    float otv;
    double ui = 0.0;
    double vi = 0.0;
    double svar;


    for (std::int32_t jvar = 1; jvar <= l2var; ++jvar) {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Calculate next m_k_vector polynomial and estimate m_v.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        NextK(itype);
        itype = CalcSc();
        Newest(itype, ui, vi);
        float vv = (float)(vi);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Estimate svar
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        float ss = 0.0;

        if (m_k_vector[m_n - 1] != 0.0) {
            ss = (float)(-m_p_vector[m_n] / m_k_vector[m_n - 1]);
        }

        float tv = 1.0;
        float ts = 1.0;

        if ((jvar != 1) && (itype != 3)) {
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //  Compute relative measures of convergence of
            //  svar and m_v sequences.
            //----------------------------------------------------------

            if (vv != 0.0) {
                tv = (float)(::fabs((vv - ovv) / vv));
            }

            if (ss != 0.0) {
                ts = (float)(::fabs((ss - oss) / ss));
            }

            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //  If decreasing, multiply two most recent convergence
            //  measures.
            //----------------------------------------------------------

            float tvv = 1.0;

            if (tv < otv) {
                tvv = tv * otv;
            }

            float tss = 1.0;

            if (ts < ots) {
                tss = ts * ots;
            }

            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //  Compare with convergence criteria.
            //----------------------------------------------------------

            bool vpass_flag = tvv < betav;
            bool spass_flag = tss < betas;

            if (spass_flag || vpass_flag) {
                //------------------------------------------------------
                //  At least one sequence has passed the convergence
                //  test. Store variables before iterating.
                //------------------------------------------------------

                double svu = m_u;
                double svv = m_v;
                std::int32_t ii = 0;

                for (ii = 0; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                    m_svk_vector[ii] = m_k_vector[ii];
                }

                svar = ss;

                //------------------------------------------------------
                //  Choose iteration according to the fastest
                //  converging sequence.
                //------------------------------------------------------

                bool vtry_flag = false;
                bool stry_flag = false;
                bool exit_outer_loop_flag = false;

                bool start_with_real_iteration_flag =
                    (spass_flag && ((!vpass_flag) || (tss < tvv)));

                do {
                    if (!start_with_real_iteration_flag) {
                        nz = QuadraticIteration(ui, vi);

                        if (nz > 0) {
                            exit_outer_loop_flag = true;
                            break;
                        }

                        //----------------------------------------------
                        //  Quadratic iteration has failed. flag
                        //  that it has been tried and decrease
                        //  the convergence criterion.
                        //----------------------------------------------

                        vtry_flag = true;
                        betav = (float)(betav * 0.25);
                    }

                    //--------------------------------------------------
                    //  Try linear iteration if it has not been
                    //  tried and the svar sequence is converging.
                    //--------------------------------------------------

                    if (((!stry_flag) && spass_flag)
                        || start_with_real_iteration_flag) {
                        if (!start_with_real_iteration_flag) {
                            for (ii = 0; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                                m_k_vector[ii] = m_svk_vector[ii];
                            }
                        } else {
                            start_with_real_iteration_flag = false;
                        }

                        std::int32_t iflag = 0;

                        nz = RealIteration(svar, iflag);

                        if (nz > 0) {
                            exit_outer_loop_flag = true;
                            break;
                        }

                        //----------------------------------------------
                        //  Linear iteration has failed. Flag that
                        //  it has been tried and decrease the
                        //  convergence criterion.
                        //----------------------------------------------

                        stry_flag = true;
                        betas = (float)(betas * 0.25);

                        if (iflag != 0) {
                            //------------------------------------------
                            //  If linear iteration signals an almost
                            //  double real zero attempt quadratic
                            //  iteration.
                            //------------------------------------------

                            ui = -(svar + svar);
                            vi = svar * svar;

                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    //--------------------------------------------------
                    //  Restore variables
                    //--------------------------------------------------

                    m_u = svu;
                    m_v = svv;

                    for (ii = 0; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                        m_k_vector[ii] = m_svk_vector[ii];
                    }

                    //----------------------------------------------
                    //  Try quadratic iteration if it has not been
                    //  tried and the m_v sequence is converging.
                    //----------------------------------------------
                } while (vpass_flag && (!vtry_flag));

                if (exit_outer_loop_flag) {
                    break;
                }

                //------------------------------------------------------
                //  Recompute m_qp_vector and scalar values to
                //  continue the second stage.
                //------------------------------------------------------

                QuadraticSyntheticDivision(m_n_plus_one,
                    m_u,
                    m_v,
                    m_p_vector.data(),
                    m_qp_vector.data(),
                    m_a,
                    m_b);

                itype = CalcSc();
            }
        }

        ovv = vv;
        oss = ss;
        otv = tv;
        ots = ts;
    }

    return nz;
}

//======================================================================
//  Variable-shift m_k_vector-polynomial iteration for
//  a quadratic factor converges only if the zeros are
//  equimodular or nearly so.
//
//    uu  Coefficients of starting quadratic
//    vv  Coefficients of starting quadratic
//
//  Return value:
//    nz  The number of zeros found.
//======================================================================

template<std::int32_t degree>
std::int32_t PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::QuadraticIteration(double uu, double vv)
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Main loop
    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    double ui = 0.0;
    double vi = 0.0;
    float omp = 0.0F;
    float relstp = 0.0F;
    std::int32_t itype = 0;
    bool tried_flag = false;
    std::int32_t jvar = 0;
    std::int32_t nz = 0;
    m_u = uu;
    m_v = vv;

    for(;;) {
        SolveQuadraticEquation(1.0,
            m_u,
            m_v,
            m_real_sz,
            m_imag_sz,
            m_real_lz,
            m_imag_lz);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Return if roots of the quadratic are real and not close
        //  to multiple or nearly equal and  of opposite sign.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        if (::fabs(::fabs(m_real_sz) - ::fabs(m_real_lz)) > 0.01 * ::fabs(m_real_lz)) {
            break;
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Evaluate polynomial by quadratic synthetic division.
        //------------------------------------------------------------------

        QuadraticSyntheticDivision(m_n_plus_one,
            m_u,
            m_v,
            m_p_vector.data(),
            m_qp_vector.data(),
            m_a,
            m_b);

        float mp = (float)(::fabs(m_a - m_real_sz * m_b) + ::fabs(m_imag_sz * m_b));

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Compute a rigorous  bound on the rounding error in
        //  evaluting m_p_vector.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        float zm = (float)(::sqrt((float)(::fabs((float)(m_v)))));
        float ee = (float)(2.0 * (float)(::fabs((float)(m_qp_vector[0]))));
        float tvar = (float)(-m_real_sz * m_b);
        std::int32_t ii = 0;

        for (ii = 1; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
            ee = ee * zm + (float)(::fabs((float)(m_qp_vector[ii])));
        }

        ee = ee * zm + (float)(::fabs((float)(m_a)+tvar));
        ee = (float)((5.0 * m_mre + 4.0 * m_are) * ee
            - (5.0 * m_mre + 2.0 * m_are) * ((float)(::fabs((float)(m_a)+tvar)) + (float)(::fabs((float)(m_b))) * zm)
            + 2.0 * m_are * (float)(::fabs(tvar)));

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Iteration has converged sufficiently if the polynomial
        //  value is less than 20 times this bound.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        if (mp <= 20.0 * ee) {
            nz = 2;
            break;
        }

        jvar = jvar + 1;

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Stop iteration after 20 steps.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        if (jvar > 20) {
            break;
        }

        if ((jvar >= 2) && ((relstp <= 0.01)
            && (mp >= omp) && (!tried_flag))) {
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //  A cluster appears to be stalling the convergence.
            //  Five fixed shift steps are taken with a m_u, m_v
            //  close to the cluster.
            //----------------------------------------------------------

            if (relstp < f_ETA) {
                relstp = f_ETA;
            }

            relstp = (float)(::sqrt(relstp));
            m_u = m_u - m_u * relstp;
            m_v = m_v + m_v * relstp;

            QuadraticSyntheticDivision(m_n_plus_one,
                m_u,
                m_v,
                m_p_vector.data(),
                m_qp_vector.data(),
                m_a,
                m_b);

            for (ii = 0; ii < 5; ++ii) {
                itype = CalcSc();
                NextK(itype);
            }

            tried_flag = true;
            jvar = 0;
        }

        omp = mp;

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Calculate next m_k_vector polynomial and
        //  new m_u and m_v.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        itype = CalcSc();
        NextK(itype);
        itype = CalcSc();
        Newest(itype, ui, vi);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  If vi is zero the iteration is not converging.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        if (vi == 0.0) {
            break;
        }

        relstp = (float)(::fabs((vi - m_v) / vi));
        m_u = ui;
        m_v = vi;
    }

    return nz;
}

//======================================================================
//  Variable-shift h polynomial iteration for a real zero.
//
//    sss      Starting iterate
//    flag     Flag to indicate a pair of zeros near real axis.
//
//  Return Value:
//     Number of zero found.
//======================================================================

template<std::int32_t degree>
std::int32_t PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::RealIteration(double &sss, std::int32_t &flag)
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Main loop
    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    double tvar = 0.0;
    float omp = 0.0F;
    std::int32_t nz = 0;
    flag = 0;
    std::int32_t jvar = 0;
    double svar = sss;

    for(;;) {
        double pv = m_p_vector[0];

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Evaluate m_p_vector at svar
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        m_qp_vector[0] = pv;
        std::int32_t ii = 0;

        for (ii = 1; ii < m_n_plus_one; ++ii) {
            pv = pv * svar + m_p_vector[ii];
            m_qp_vector[ii] = pv;
        }

        float mp = (float)(::fabs(pv));

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Compute a rigorous bound on the error in evaluating p
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        double ms = (double)(::fabs(svar));
        double ee = (m_mre / (m_are + m_mre)) * (double)(::fabs((double)(m_qp_vector[0])));

        for (ii = 1; ii < m_n_plus_one; ++ii) {
            ee = ee * ms + (float)(::fabs((double)(m_qp_vector[ii])));
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Iteration has converged sufficiently if the
        //  polynomial value is less than 20 times this bound.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        if (mp <= 20.0 * ((m_are + m_mre) * ee - m_mre * mp)) {
            nz = 1;
            m_real_sz = svar;
            m_imag_sz = 0.0;
            break;
        }

        jvar = jvar + 1;

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Stop iteration after 10 steps.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        if (jvar > 10) {
            break;
        }

        if ((jvar >= 2)
            && ((::fabs(tvar) <= 0.001 * ::fabs(svar - tvar))
                && (mp > omp))) {
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //  A cluster of zeros near the real axis has been
            //  encountered. Return with flag set to initiate
            //  a quadratic iteration.
            //----------------------------------------------------------

            flag = 1;
            sss = svar;
            break;
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Return if the polynomial value has increased significantly.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        omp = mp;

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Compute t, the next polynomial, and the new iterate.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        double kv = m_k_vector[0];
        m_qk_vector[0] = kv;

        for (ii = 1; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
            kv = kv * svar + m_k_vector[ii];
            m_qk_vector[ii] = kv;
        }

        if (::fabs(kv) <= ::fabs(m_k_vector[m_n - 1]) * f_ETA_N) {
            m_k_vector[0] = 0.0;

            for (ii = 1; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                m_k_vector[ii] = m_qk_vector[ii - 1];
            }
        } else {
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //  Use the scaled form of the recurrence if the
            //  value of m_k_vector at svar is non-zero.
            //----------------------------------------------------------

            tvar = -pv / kv;
            m_k_vector[0] = m_qp_vector[0];

            for (ii = 1; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                m_k_vector[ii] = tvar * m_qk_vector[ii - 1] + m_qp_vector[ii];
            }
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Use unscaled form.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        kv = m_k_vector[0];

        for (ii = 1; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
            kv = kv * svar + m_k_vector[ii];
        }

        tvar = 0.0;

        if (::fabs(kv) > ::fabs(m_k_vector[m_n - 1]) * f_ETA_N) {
            tvar = -pv / kv;
        }

        svar = svar + tvar;
    }

    return nz;
}

//======================================================================
//  This routine calculates scalar quantities used to compute
//  the next m_k_vector polynomial and new estimates of the
//  quadratic coefficients.
//
//  Return Value:
//    type  std::int32_teger variable set here indicating how the
//    calculations are normalized to avoid overflow.
//======================================================================

template<std::int32_t degree>
std::int32_t PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::CalcSc()
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Synthetic division of m_k_vector by the quadratic 1, m_u, m_v.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    QuadraticSyntheticDivision(m_n,
        m_u,
        m_v,
        m_k_vector.data(),
        m_qk_vector.data(),
        m_c,
        m_d);

    std::int32_t itype = 0;

    if ((::fabs(m_c) <= ::fabs(m_k_vector[m_n - 1]) * f_ETA_N_SQUARED)
        && (::fabs(m_d) <= ::fabs(m_k_vector[m_n - 2]) * f_ETA_N_SQUARED)) {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  itype == 3 Indicates the quadratic is almost a
        //  factor of m_k_vector.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        itype = 3;
    } else if (::fabs(m_d) >= ::fabs(m_c)) {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  itype == 2 Indicates that all formulas are divided by m_d.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        itype = 2;
        m_e = m_a / m_d;
        m_f = m_c / m_d;
        m_g = m_u * m_b;
        m_h = m_v * m_b;
        m_a3 = (m_a + m_g) * m_e + m_h * (m_b / m_d);
        m_a1 = m_b * m_f - m_a;
        m_a7 = (m_f + m_u) * m_a + m_h;
    } else {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  itype == 1 Indicates that all formulas are divided by m_c.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        itype = 1;
        m_e = m_a / m_c;
        m_f = m_d / m_c;
        m_g = m_u * m_e;
        m_h = m_v * m_b;
        m_a3 = m_a * m_e + (m_h / m_c + m_g) * m_b;
        m_a1 = m_b - m_a * (m_d / m_c);
        m_a7 = m_a + m_g * m_d + m_h * m_f;
    }

    return itype;

}

//======================================================================
//  Computes the next k polynomials using scalars computed in CalcSc.
//======================================================================
template<std::int32_t degree>
void PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::NextK(std::int32_t itype)
{
    std::int32_t ii = 0;

    if (itype == 3) {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Use unscaled form of the recurrence if type is 3.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        m_k_vector[0] = 0.0;
        m_k_vector[1] = 0.0;

        for (ii = 2; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
            m_k_vector[ii] = m_qk_vector[ii - 2];
        }
    } else {
        double temp = m_a;

        if (itype == 1) {
            temp = m_b;
        }

        if (::fabs(m_a1) <= ::fabs(temp) * f_ETA_N) {
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //  If m_a1 is nearly zero then use a special form of
            //  the recurrence.
            //----------------------------------------------------------

            m_k_vector[0] = 0.0;
            m_k_vector[1] = -m_a7 * m_qp_vector[0];

            for (ii = 2; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                m_k_vector[ii] = m_a3 * m_qk_vector[ii - 2] - m_a7 * m_qp_vector[ii - 1];
            }
        } else {
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //  Use scaled form of the recurrence.
            //----------------------------------------------------------

            m_a7 = m_a7 / m_a1;
            m_a3 = m_a3 / m_a1;
            m_k_vector[0] = m_qp_vector[0];
            m_k_vector[1] = m_qp_vector[1] - m_a7 * m_qp_vector[0];

            for (ii = 2; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
                m_k_vector[ii] =
                    m_a3 * m_qk_vector[ii - 2] - m_a7 * m_qp_vector[ii - 1] + m_qp_vector[ii];
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

//======================================================================
//  Compute new estimates of the quadratic coefficients using the
//  scalars computed in CalcSc.
//======================================================================

template<std::int32_t degree>
void PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::Newest(std::int32_t itype, double &uu, double &vv)
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Use formulas appropriate to setting of itype.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    if (itype == 3) {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  If itype == 3 the quadratic is zeroed.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        uu = 0.0;
        vv = 0.0;
    } else {
        double a4;
        double a5;

        if (itype == 2) {
            a4 = (m_a + m_g) * m_f + m_h;
            a5 = (m_f + m_u) * m_c + m_v * m_d;
        } else {
            a4 = m_a + m_u * m_b + m_h * m_f;
            a5 = m_c + (m_u + m_v * m_f) * m_d;
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Evaluate new quadratic coefficients.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        double b1 = -m_k_vector[m_n - 1] / m_p_vector[m_n];
        double b2 = -(m_k_vector[m_n - 2] + b1 * m_p_vector[m_n - 1]) / m_p_vector[m_n];
        double c1 = m_v * b2 * m_a1;
        double c2 = b1 * m_a7;
        double c3 = b1 * b1 * m_a3;
        double c4 = c1 - c2 - c3;
        double temp = a5 + b1 * a4 - c4;

        if (temp != 0.0) {
            uu = m_u - (m_u * (c3 + c2) + m_v * (b1 * m_a1 + b2 * m_a7)) / temp;
            vv = m_v * (1.0 + c4 / temp);
        }
    }

    return;
}

//======================================================================
//  Divides p by the quadratic  1, u, v placing the quotient in q
//  and the remainder in a,b
//======================================================================

template<std::int32_t degree>
void PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::QuadraticSyntheticDivision(std::int32_t n_plus_one,
    double u,
    double v,
    double *p_ptr,
    double *q_ptr,
    double &a,
    double &b)
{
    b = p_ptr[0];
    q_ptr[0] = b;
    a = p_ptr[1] - u * b;
    q_ptr[1] = a;

    for (std::int32_t ii = 2; ii < n_plus_one; ++ii) {
        double c = p_ptr[ii] - u * a - v * b;
        q_ptr[ii] = c;
        b = a;
        a = c;
    }

    return;
}

//======================================================================
//                                          2
//  Calculate the zeros of the quadratic a x + b x + c.
//  the quadratic formula, modified to avoid overflow, is used to find
//  the larger zero if the zeros are real and both zeros are complex.
//  the smaller real zero is found directly from the product of the
//  zeros c / a.
//======================================================================

template<std::int32_t degree>
void PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::SolveQuadraticEquation(double a,
    double b,
    double c,
    double &sr,
    double &si,
    double &lr,
    double &li)
{
    if (a == 0.0) {
        if (b != 0.0) {
            sr = -c / b;
        } else {
            sr = 0.0;
        }

        lr = 0.0;
        si = 0.0;
        li = 0.0;
    } else if (c == 0.0) {
        sr = 0.0;
        lr = -b / a;
        si = 0.0;
        li = 0.0;
    } else {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Compute discriminant avoiding overflow.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        double d;
        double e;
        double bvar = b / 2.0;

        if (::fabs(bvar) < ::fabs(c)) {
            if (c < 0.0) {
                e = -a;
            } else {
                e = a;
            }

            e = bvar * (bvar / ::fabs(c)) - e;

            d = ::sqrt(::fabs(e)) * ::sqrt(::fabs(c));
        } else {
            e = 1.0 - (a / bvar) * (c / bvar);
            d = ::sqrt(::fabs(e)) * ::fabs(bvar);
        }

        if (e >= 0.0) {
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //  Real zeros
            //----------------------------------------------------------

            if (bvar >= 0.0) {
                d = -d;
            }

            lr = (-bvar + d) / a;
            sr = 0.0;

            if (lr != 0.0) {
                sr = (c / lr) / a;
            }

            si = 0.0;
            li = 0.0;
        } else {
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //  Complex conjugate zeros
            //----------------------------------------------------------

            sr = -bvar / a;
            lr = sr;
            si = ::fabs(d / a);
            li = -si;
        }
    }

    return;
}
#endif
```

`main.cc`

```
/* standard headers */
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

/* omp headers */
#include <omp.h>

/* png headers */
#include "png.hh"

/* note: I did not create the polynomial related files I got them from here
 * and yes I know this has terrible code quailty but I could not find anything better
  https://www.codeproject.com/articles/674149/a-real-polynomial-class-with-root-finder 
 */
#include "PolynomialRootFinder.hh"

/* constants */
namespace
{
    constexpr std::uint32_t width = 500;
    constexpr std::uint32_t height = 500;
    constexpr std::int32_t degree = 24;
    constexpr std::int32_t coefficients = degree + 1;
    constexpr std::uint64_t total_samples = 1000000;
    std::uint64_t const individual_samples = total_samples / omp_get_max_threads();
    using roots_t = std::array<double, coefficients * 2>;
    using heatmap_t = std::uint32_t;
}


std::int32_t generate_roots(roots_t &output)
{
    static thread_local std::mt19937_64 mt(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::int32_t> dist(0, 1);

    std::array<double, coefficients> cofs;
    std::transform(cofs.begin(), cofs.end(), cofs.begin(), [&](auto) { return dist(mt) ? 1 : -1; });
    PolynomialRootFinder<degree> poly = {};

    std::int32_t roots_found;
    if (poly.FindRoots(&cofs[0], &output[0], &output[coefficients], &roots_found) == PolynomialRootFinder<degree>::RootStatus_T::SUCCESS) {
        return roots_found;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void generate_heatmap(std::vector<heatmap_t> &heatmap, heatmap_t &max_value)
{
    roots_t roots = {};
    auto map_range = [](auto s, decltype(s) a1, decltype(s) a2, decltype(s) b1, decltype(s) b2) {
        return b1 + (s - a1) * (b2 - b1) / (a2 - a1);
    };

    for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < individual_samples; ++i) {
        /* see if we found any roots */
        if (std::int32_t roots_found = generate_roots(roots)) {
            /* plot all the roots found to the heatmap */
            while (--roots_found >= 0) {
                double const real = roots[roots_found];
                double const imag = roots[static_cast<std::size_t>(roots_found) + coefficients];

                std::int32_t const col = static_cast<std::int32_t>(map_range(real, -1.6, 1.6, 0, width));
                std::int32_t const row = static_cast<std::int32_t>(map_range(imag, -1.6, 1.6, 0, height));
                /* only plot roots that are in bounds */
                if (col < 0 || col >= width || row < 0 || row >= height) continue;
                max_value = std::max(++heatmap[static_cast<std::size_t>(row) * width + col], max_value);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    /* create a heatmap*/
    std::vector<heatmap_t> heatmap(width * height);

    /* start a timer */
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> const t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    /* generate heatmap */
    heatmap_t max_value = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
    generate_heatmap(heatmap, max_value);

    /* write image */
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> image;
    image.resize(width * height);
    for (std::int32_t i = 0; i < width * height; ++i) {
            std::uint8_t color = static_cast<std::uint8_t>((std::log(heatmap[i]) / std::log(max_value)) * 255.0 + 0.55555);
            image[i] = color;
    }
    png::write_image("output.png", image.data(), width, height);

    /* print the time it took */
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> const t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> const duration =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
    double const time_took = duration.count();
    std::printf("It took %f %s", time_took, std::array{ "seconds", "second" } [1.0 == time_took]);

    /* wait for user input to close */
    (void)std::getchar();
}
```

here is what the program produces:

[image]

Comment: Since your file contains a copyright notice. I would just also point out that any code put on a stack exchange site is also released under a [creative commons license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) (its a condition of posting, see bottom of page for details). It does not affect this code much but just for future reference if you want to post code under a difference license.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Variable names

There are a lot of variables with very short names. I know it is common in mathematical formulas to use single-letter names for variables, but you will at least find some accompanying text that explains what all the letters means. I would at least add some comments to the code at the place where you declare variabels like `double m_a`. This can be a short epxlaination, or perhaps a reference to a paper or book, including the number of the formula where it is first introduced. Alternatively, give the variables a longer, but more descriptive name.

On the other hand, some variables are bit long, and can be shorted. For example, variables referring to arrays or vectors are commonly written using the plural form, and we don't have to repeat the type in the name. So for example, instead of `coefficient_vector_ptr`, write `coefficients`.

## Use `std::complex` for complex variables

Instead of declaring two variables, one for the real and the other for the imaginary part, consider declaring a single [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) variable. You can still access the two components individually if needed, but it reduces the amount of variables, and there are also a lot of mathematical functions that can work directly on complex variables.

## Use `const` pointers where appropriate

I see some use of `constexpr`, but almost no occurence of `const`. Whenever you are passing a pointer to something to a function, and you are not modifying the contents, make it a `const` pointer. This will catch errors if you accidentily do write to a `const` variable, and it might give the compiler some more opportunities to optimize the code. For example, `filename` and `image_data` in `write_image()`, and `coefficient_vector_ptr` in `FindRoots()` can be made `const` pointers.

## Avoid casting unnecessarily

I see a lot of casts that seem unnecessary. For example:

```
xvar = (double)(::fabs((double)(m_p_vector[ii])));
```

Why the casts when `m_p_vector` is already an array of `double`s, and `xvar` is also a `double`? I would also avoid using the C library version of `fabs()`, and use `std::fabs()` instead:

```
xvar = std::fabs(m_p_vector[ii]);
```

Also note that C++, for better or for worse, will perform implicit casts and type promotions for you in some cases. They generally reduce the amount of casting necessary. Take for example:

```
std::int32_t lvar = (std::int32_t)(::log(sc) / ::log(f_BASE) + 0.5);
double factor = ::pow((double)(f_BASE * 1.0), double(lvar));
```

This can be rewritten to:

```
std::int32_t lvar = std::log(sc) / std::log(f_BASE) + 0.5;
double factor = std::pow(f_BASE * 1.0, lvar);
```

Note that it not only is shorter, it is even more efficient in this case: `std::pow()` has an overload for integer exponents, and can use a much faster algorithm to calculate the result in that case.

## Avoid hoisting degenerate cases out of loops

I see this pattern repeated a lot of times:

```
double kv = m_k_vector[0];
m_qk_vector[0] = kv;

for (ii = 1; ii < m_n; ++ii) {
    kv = kv * svar + m_k_vector[ii];
    m_qk_vector[ii] = kv;
}
```

Here you treat `ii = 0` as a special case and have moved it out of the loop. But it can be rewritten to:

```
double kv = 0;

for (ii = 0; i < m_n; ++ii) {
    kv = kv * svar + m_k_vector[ii];
    m_qk_vector[ii] = kv;
}
```

There is probably no difference in speed, but the latter is just simpler code, and it tells you that there is actually nothing special about the first element.

## Use `auto` to avoid repeating (long) types

While I wouldn't use `auto` for most of the maths, it can be used effectively inside `main()` to avoid repeating yourself. For example:

```
auto const t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
...
    auto color = static_cast<std::uint8_t>((std::log(heatmap[i]) / std::log(max_value)) * 255.0 + 0.55555);
...
auto const t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = t2 - t1;
```